# Activating Communities through Matching Licenses

Tags: community, customer-community

I just wanted to know regarding activation of communities. I see it can be done via refresh in sandbox environments however is there any way it can be done through Setup -> Company Profile -> Match Licenses or would it REQUIRE refresh?

Is it possible??